# Delete corrupted items after import

Tags: packages

I've installed a package with corrupted items (that means the items need some base clases and so on and when I try to click on such an item I get an error - I don't have these classes inside my project and getting them is not an option)

[image]

Details

[image]

So I can't call the submenu and I can't search for these items. How can I delete these items from my tree?

Comment: /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx

Comment: If you are using TDS for item serialization, you can use this tool to delete these items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Mark Cassidy pointed out in his comment. The best remedy in this situation is `DbBrowser`.

1. Log in to your authoring instance as an admin.
2. Navigate to /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx

From there, you will see your content tree. You can navigate to the problem items and either delete the single item or delete children.

[image: DbBrowser]

DbBrowser is a slimmed down version of Content Editor and typically provides access when Content Editor does not.